# "The wind is blowing of the fan" vs. "The wind is blowing from the fan"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the difference between "of" and "from" in the following sentences:

> The wind is blowing of the fan.
>
> The wind is blowing from the fan.

Not sure if they are properly worded!

Comment: Most people would probably speak of *"the breeze blown **by** the fan"* (for most fans, "wind" is a bit strong, but it's the fan doing the blowing, not the moving air itself in this context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers-  
Thanks. But WikiHow has a similar sentence: The air blowing from the fan (using air instead of wind, though) wikihow.com/Stay-Cool-During-the-Summer

Comment: Nothing is hard-and-fast. But the Wikihow usage is more common. Even saying *"the **breeze** is blowing from the fan"* sounds a bit "tautological" to me - I'd just say it's ***coming** from the fan*. Words like breeze, wind, etc. denote *already-moving air*, which usually *blows from a direction*, or *is blown by something (usually, a fan)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence,

> The wind is blowing of the fan.

is uncommon to the point where I think most would take it to be a typographical error (perhaps *blowing out of the fan* or *blowing off the fan*).

You would say

> The wind is blowing from the fan.

to indicate that the wind originates from the fan or from the direction of the fan.

Comment: And what is the difference between 'off' and 'from' as in your examples?

Comment: *Off* simply indicates separation, not direction or origin: dust billowing off the hillside, cars streaming off the highway, detectives coming off a case. *From* is more general and can indicate either the source or the direction where the source lies. We can speak of the breeze blowing from the north, or the left side of the room, or the vent that should have been closed before the party.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is fine. The first sentence seems wrong.

'X is of the Y' is a correct if uncommon usage, e.g.

> The barbarian is of the north.
>
> The machine is of the older type.

But the insertion of 'blowing' before 'of' is I think incorrect. 'is of' is a descriptive term; 'is blowing of' doesn't work.

'Is blowing off' from choster's answer works, because 'blowing off' is a valid fragment on its own, and for the same reason 'blowing from' works. Both 'blowing off' and 'blowing from' are descriptions of what the air is doing and could be used interchangeably.